# JavaScript - increasing a global variable as function argument

Tags: javascript

If i have code, where i want in console "0 1" instead of "0 0"

```
function increase(f) { f++; }
var n = 0;
console.log(n);
increase(n);
console.log(n);
```

How to increase in such way the variable. I wish use like in c-language &v. Is it possible?

Comment: pass an object instead of a primitive value.

Comment: just have to use `n = increase(n);`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gurvinder372!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing `increase` can do to the parameter `f` that will affect the variable `n` in your example.

When you do `increase(n)`, the **value** of `n` is passed into `increase`. That value is not in any way linked to the variable `n`.

(This is called "pass by value;" JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language, [more in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).)

Instead, have `increase` *return* the new value, and assign it to `n`.